# I have an int[] member in a class that reassings value to every instance of the class with each new declaration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class for saving interactions in a game, when a person reacts takes values from the status of the game to create a new instance of this class, then send it, this is fine, the  problem is when I try to get the value at the end of the level, then every instance of the class has the same value for that property with coincides with the last object declared of that class

```cs
public class reactionOrOmission
{
    public bool reacted
    {
        get { return _reacted; }
        set { _reacted = value; }
    }
    public float reactionTime
    {
        get { return _reactionTime; }
        set { _reactionTime = value; }
    }
    public bool correct
    {
        get { return _correct; }
        set { _correct = value; }
    }
    public int[] flagType
    {
        get { return _flagType; }
        set { _flagType = value; }
    }
    public float generalTime
    {
        get { return _generalTime; }
        set { _generalTime = value; }
    }

    public string focus
    {
        get
        {
            return _focus != null ? _focus : "non_focusable";
        }
        set { _focus = value; }
    }

    private bool _reacted;
    private float _reactionTime;
    private bool _correct;
    private int[] _flagType;
    private float _generalTime;
    private string _focus;

    public reactionOrOmission(bool Reacted, float ReactionTime, bool Correct, int[] FlagType, float GeneralTime)
    {
        reacted = Reacted;
        reactionTime = ReactionTime;
        correct = Correct;
        flagType = FlagType;
        generalTime = GeneralTime;
        if (Tobii.Gaming.TobiiAPI.GetFocusedObject() == null)
        {
            focus = "non_focusable";
        }
        else
        {
           ///nonimportant///
        }
    }
}
```

Thought it may have been something relating to an integer array but i have tried arrayList and list and the same happens.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - there's a lot of irrelevant code here (which could be *much* simpler using automatically implemented properties) but we're missing the crucial code where you actually call the constructor. My guess is that you're only ever creating one array instance, but we can't see the code that does that...

Comment: Note that an array is a reference type, so assigning it will not copy the array, it just assigns a reference to the same array. But the problem is not visible in the code you provided. A usage example would be required.

Comment: Hey, could you tell us how to call that piece of code. Looks like there is no problem here. So maybe your caller is creating the issue (using Linq or anything else...).

Comment: Like the others, I'm not quite following what you are trying to say.  But, as a wild guess, try changing `flagType = FlagType;` in your constructor to `flagType = FlagType.ToArray()`.  This will make a copy of the `FlagType` array.

Comment: hello this is the declaration `<reactionOrOmission r = new reactionOrOmission(true, Time.time - reactionTime, CorrectSeries, actualFlags, Time.time - levelmanager.startTime);
            reactionsList.Add(r);` im posting this as a comment i dont know if its correct if not dont hesitate to tell me

Comment: You can always edit your question and add missing information there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your class is correct but you use incorrect instances or maybe incorrect usage after create instances...I ran your class and set 4 different instance , each instance has different values.
so your usage of class is incorrect!

Comment: hello i added a comment in the original post, that is the only declaration of the class im making, but the problem stands when i create a new instance (or add one into the list) every each one of the flag type in the list updates acording to the last one, but only that the other values stay the same

Comment: @oscuro08, show us a short reproducible usage example where the problem occurs. We need an example we can copy paste into our Visual Studio, so that we can run and analyze it. From the code posted in the question and in the comments so far, this is not possible.